Кто какой софт использует для написания и отладки скриптов?
У меня удаленный сервер на линукс.
Как я пишу пайтон скрипт для выполнения его на сервере.
Подключаюсь через WinSCP, открываю пайтон скрипт в Visual Studio Code. Редактирую...
Для запуска скрипта, подключаюсь через patty по ssh. Запускаю скрипт, смотрю в консоль...
К примеру выполняю команду FFMPEG, запустил, времени занимает около часа. Если что то в скрипте сделал не так, забыл или еще что та.
Закрываю консоль, завершая процесс ffmpeg. Не знаю как его остановить в процессе, если есть возможность такая, то как? Две консоли открыть, чтобы во второй выполнить команду по завершению процесс? В первой консоли, процесс ffmpeg не дает написать команду...
По новой открываю patty, по новой запускаю ffmpeg... Перед этим делаю поправки в скрипте...
И так каждый раз...

Если на машине с Линукс есть лишние 2 ГБ оперативки, то используй расширение https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh для отладки и кодинга прямо на сервере. Пошаговая отладка, запуск, прерывание с кнопки и всё такое будет доступно.
Комбинация ctrl+z останавливает процесс и выводит обратно в шелл. Можно прибить команду kill %1 где %1 это номер фонового процесса. Возобновить процесс можно командами bg и fg. bg - команда работает в фоне и если не срёт в консоль, то можно параллельно ещё что-то поделать. Команда fg возобновляет команду на переднем плане.
